# Will the block contains references to self?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
-(void) vAfterMainVariable
{
    __weak BGGeneralCatalogView * weakSelf=self;
    [_loAIOnebyOne vLoadStuffsWithURLBlock:^(){
        NSString * URL= [weakSelf strGetURLToDownloadStuffs];
        return URL;
    } andPermaToastMessage: @"Loading Catalog" andCompletionBlock:^{}];
    //[self.loAIOnebyOne vLoadStuffsWithURLBlock:<#^NSString *(void)blURL#> andPermaToastMessage:<#(NSString *)#> andCompletionBlock:<#^(void)completionBlock#>]
}

-(NSString *) strGetURLToDownloadStuffs
{
    NSString * URL = [BGMakeURL URLforGetCatalogID:self.arArray];
    return URL;
}
```

I uses weakSelf in the block. Yet, that weakSelf refer to a function that call self.arArray

So will the block has any strong pointer to self? When self, which is a viewController is gone from navigationController will it be deallocated soon?

To be exact, the block does NOT refer to self. The block refer to weakSelf that calls a method that refer to self. However the self in that method is the weakSelf.

Basically I followed that with this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_loAIOnebyOne vCancelAllStuffs];
}
```

And it turns out dealloc is simply not called until after the block is finish. So the block must have contained self. But how?

Also how do I know which object still refer to my object?

The only object that refer to my object should be the UINavigationController object. The next one would be the block which is executing on the stack.

Comment: What you are doing is fine.

Comment: in practice what would the point be of creating a possible strong retain cycle?

Comment: actually self does not have a pointer to the block. I just don't want to wait till the block is finish running till self is deallocated. So the stack has references to the block.

Comment: You can't rely on dealloc ever being called. There are many cases where your object will not be deleted at any predictable point in time.

Comment: Says who? At ARC objects are deleted predictably

Comment: Actually, not really. First of course dealloc will never be called if your app is terminated. Second, calls to dealloc can be delayed. MacOS X and iOS try to do deallocs in the background to avoid putting pressure on the main thread.

Comment: @gnasher729: That is new to me, do you have any reference? As far as I know, an object is deallocated immediately as soon as the last strong reference is gone (retain count drops to zero).

Comment: Actually is there a way to know what object still refer to the viewController?

Answer (score -3):

weakSelf needs to be a block variable. When the block is copied, it creates its own variable containing a copy of weakSelf, and that copy isn't weak.

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is wrong. The copy of `weakSelf` captured by the block is also weak.